# Show stock details by each sales

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to select data from `ProdcutStock` table by grouping it with each client, sales.

My Tables are as below

`SalesMaster`

```
Id  CustId  TDate
1   2       2016-06-03
2   1       2016-06-03
3   2       2016-06-06
4   2       2016-06-06
5   1       2016-06-06
6   3       2016-06-06
```

`SalesDetails`

```
Id  SalesId ProductId   Qty
1   1       2       4.00
2   1       1       5.00
3   2       2       21.00
4   2       2       88.00
5   2       1       8.00
6   2       3       9.00
7   2       3       4.00
8   2       1       77.00
9   2       2       4.00
10  2       3       8.00
11  2       2       7.00
12  3       2       41.00
13  3       3       10.00
14  4       2       25.00
15  4       1       49.00
16  5       3       50.00
17  5       1       50.00
18  6       2       10.00
19  6       3       20.00
```

`ProductStock`

```
Id  Date    OpeningStock    TotalProduction TotalSales  ClosingStock
1   2016-06-05  100.00      0.00            0.00        100.00
2   2016-06-06  100.00      325.00          255.00      170.00
3   2016-06-07  200.00      0.00            0.00        200.00
5   2016-06-08  200.00      0.00            0.00        200.00
6   2016-06-09  200.00      0.00            0.00        200.00
7   2016-06-10  200.00      0.00            0.00        200.00
```

What I am trying to achieve is the below table

```
Date    OpeningStock    Production  Sales   Customer    ClosingStock
2016-06-05  100.00      0.00        0.00    NULL        100.00
2016-06-06  100.00      325.00      125.00  XYZ         300.00
2016-06-06  300.00      0.00        30.00   ABC         270.00
2016-06-06  270.00      0.00        100.00  PQR         170.00
2016-06-07  170.00      0.00        0.00    NULL        200.00
```

What I am getting using code below: (**See Opening and Closing Stock**)

```
Date    Opening Production  Sales   Name    Closing
2016-06-05  100.00  0.00    0.00    NULL    100.00
2016-06-06  100.00  325.00  125.00  XYZ     300.00
2016-06-06  100.00  325.00  30.00   ABC     395.00
2016-06-06  100.00  325.00  100.00  PQR     325.00
2016-06-07  200.00  0.00    0.00    NULL    200.00
```

What I have done is as below:

```
SELECT PS.Date, PS.OpeningStock , PS.TotalProduction
, SUM(COALESCE(SD.Qty,0)) AS SALES, CM.Name
, (COALESCE(PS.OpeningStock,0)) + COALESCE(PS.TotalProduction,0) - SUM(COALESCE(SD.Qty,0)) AS ClosingStock
FROM ProductStock PS LEFT JOIN SalesMaster SM ON PS.Date = SM.Date
LEFT JOIN SalesDetails SD ON SM.Id = SD.SalesId
LEFT JOIN CustomersMaster CM ON SM.CustomerId = CM.Id
GROUP BY PS.Date, CM.Name, PS.OpeningStock, PS.TotalProduction
ORDER BY PS.Date
```

I also tried to work with `LAG` as I am using SQL Server 2012 but I didn't get how to apply.

Comment: Please add CustomersMaster table.

Comment: @vercelli : It wasn't required as I wanted only name from that table. JamieD77's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660162/show-stock-details-by-each-sales#37661243) worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you close.  You can use SUM() OVER() to get a running total of SALES and just calculate the Quantities using that.

```
;WITH ProductDetail AS (
    SELECT  ps.[Date],
            ps.OpeningStock,
            ps.TotalProduction,
            ps.ClosingStock,
            sm.CustId,
            COALESCE(SUM(Qty),0) Sales,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ps.[Date] ORDER BY CustID) Rn,
            SUM(SUM(Qty)) OVER (PARTITION BY ps.[Date] ORDER BY CustID) SalesRunningTotal
    FROM    ProductStock ps
            LEFT JOIN SalesMaster sm ON ps.[Date] = sm.[Date]
            LEFT JOIN SalesDetail sd ON sd.SalesID = sm.ID
    GROUP BY ps.[Date],
            ps.OpeningStock,
            ps.TotalProduction,
            ps.ClosingStock,
            sm.CustId
)
SELECT  [Date],
        CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN OpeningStock ELSE OpeningStock + (TotalProduction - SalesRunningTotal + Sales) END OpeningStock,
        CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN TotalProduction ELSE 0 END [Production],
        Sales,
        CustId,
        CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN OpeningStock + TotalProduction - Sales 
            ELSE OpeningStock + (TotalProduction - SalesRunningTotal) 
            END [ClosingStock]
FROM    ProductDetail
```

Comment: Thanks mate this worked perfectly. Exactly what I was trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you do not directly refer to the ID in **ProductStock**.  Did you notice that the information that is wrong was directly pulled from **ProductStock**?  For instance for the date that repeats three times, 2016-06-06, all three are 100 but on **ProductStock** only the first one is 100.  And again for **TotalProduction**.  All three are 325 when only the first one is 325.  Since you only refer them by the date and not the ID they are going to pull incorrect information (**what is the point of the ID if you are not going to use it?**).

```
2016-06-06 a
2016-06-06 b
2016-06-06 c
```

See from this set I just created I can not pull the correct letter based off of the date (which is what your query is attempting to do).  If I wanted to, in this specific case, I would have to order it by the letters and then get the letter based off of its row number (row number will equal its sequence in the alphabet).

```
1 2016-06-06 a
2 2016-06-06 b
3 2016-06-06 c
```

Now I do not have to use the row number.  I have an ID for each one so I can simply just use that to get a piece of information that I want.  You are missing the utilization of the ID in ProductStock.

(your query untouched)

```
FROM ProductStock PS LEFT JOIN SalesMaster SM ON PS.Date = SM.Date
LEFT JOIN SalesDetails SD ON SM.Id = SD.SalesId
LEFT JOIN CustomersMaster CM ON SM.CustomerId = CM.Id
GROUP BY PS.Date, CM.Name, PS.OpeningStock, PS.TotalProduction
ORDER BY PS.Date
```

The only IDs you refer to are the Customer IDs in **SalesMaster** and **CustomersMaster** and IDs in **SalesMaster** and **SalesDetails**.  In this case since you already have all yours joins you could quite simply just add a **WHERE** clause towards the end that is...

```
WHERE PS.ID = SM.ID
```

I hope this helps :)